# Unable to select specific faces in shading mode

Tags: modeling, texturing, selection-tools

I wanna select the faces of the little band around the handle but for some reason when I try to select nothing happens. Not even in object mode I get the orange outline that's usually there. I've tried restarting the program few times but it didn't help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have overlays turned off. This means that selected objects (and Faces, Vertices, etc) will not appear to be selected, because the blue/yellow/orange highlighting that indicates an object is selected is considered an overlay.

You can turn overlays back on by clicking the relevant button here:

[image]

Comment: Man, that one was golden...

Comment: I've must have accidentally switched it off when i was turning xray off, thank you for your answer!